# Linux Mint 12 on HP Pavillion DV7 - Wireless is not working

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi

I just installed Linux Mint 12 using mint4win just to test it out. I have a problem with my wireless connection.

When I start Mint, it sees the network I wish to join, I select it, enter the correct password, and 1 minute later I am being prompted for a password again. During that waiting time, I was not connected at all.

It appears if I turn off my Wireless (by tapping on the Wireless LED on the laptop), it wont turn on again either.

My Ethernet port is broken as well, so I cannot connect with a cable either. In Windows I can connect fine using Wireless.

Is there any drivers required for this to work? I cant seem to find any, and they have to be downloadable from Windows so I can put them on an USB and run them in Mint.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: My Wireless chip is an Atheros AR9285

Answer (score 1):

Found the driver - http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Download/stable/