# Under Mint 12 on an HP Pavillion DV7, my wireless stopped working

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

My wireless worked when I first installed.  I needed to turn it off for a while, so I clicked "off" in the pulldown dialog.  I used the wired network for awhile, but when I went to turn my wireless back on, it started connecting for half a second then dropping the connection. I can use the wired interface but my office doesnt have a wire so I have to go out into a common room to work.  Very irritating.  Can anyone help me?  Note that this isn't the same problem as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37682/linux-mint-12-on-hp-pavillion-dv7-wireless-is-not-working), as he never had wireless afaict.  Maybe it is and I don't understand something.

UPDATE: The device is a Atheros AR5B91, and dmesg is reporting the following:

```
[  314.769728] wlan0: authenticate with 00:22:3f:80:10:fc
[  314.787528] wlan0: send auth to 00:22:3f:80:10:fc (try 1/3)
[  314.789526] wlan0: authenticated
[  314.804098] wlan0: associate with 00:22:3f:80:10:fc (try 1/3)
[  314.806466] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:22:3f:80:10:fc (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=3)
[  314.806470] wlan0: associated
[  316.024238] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:22:3f:80:10:fc by local choice (reason=3)
```

Comment: What is the wireless card? Does it work if you run from a live-CD?

Comment: @Renan Thanks for the comment.  Yes, it worked off of the live-CD.  It also worked after a new install.  I'm trying to determine the exact wireless chipset now.

Comment: @Renan I've updated my question with more information.

Comment: This hasn't been a problem since switching to Mint 13.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere there is a security setting that I have tripped, I suspect.  What fixed the problem was enabling security on the router.  Prior to this, I have been using an access list of MAC addresses with an open wifi router.  I'm not sure what changed, but, I somehow turned security of some kind on is my hypothesis.

If I get time I'll research what changed and report here.